# How do you search for a specific string in a linked list and return that value?

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

I have a program that takes in input with 5 parameters. The inputs are video title, url, comment, length, and rating. Then sorts them based on title. The user will need to specify **insert** (to enter the video information), **lookup** (look up a video by title and print ONLY that video and its information associated with it), or **print** (just simply print everything).

**for example**

input:

```
insert
Arthur Benjamin: Lightning calculation and other "Mathemagic"
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4vqr3_ROIk
Hard to believe.
15.25  
4  
lookup  
Arthur Benjamin: Lightning calculation and other "Mathemagic"
```

output:

```
Arthur Benjamin: Lightning calculation and other "Mathemagic" , http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4vqr3_ROIk, Hard to believe., 15.25, 4
```

my problem is dealing with **lookup** in main

```
if(user == "lookup")
        {
            getline(cin, title);
            if(vlistObj -> lookup(videoObj))
            {
                vlistObj->print();
            }
        }
```

and also **lookup** in my linked list

```
bool Vlist::lookup(Video *other)
{
  Node *node = m_head;
  return node->m_next -> m_video->GetTitle() == other-> GetTitle();
}
```

I am honestly very lost on how to make **lookup** search for a specific title (assuming lots of video title/info has been given) and only print what I ask (assuming it's in the list).

Here is the complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class Video {

  public:
    Video(string video_title, string video_link, string video_comment, double video_length, int video_number);
    void print();
    const string& GetTitle() const { return title; }

  private:

    std::string title;
    string link;
    string comment;
    double length;
    int rating;

};


Video::Video(string video_title, string video_link, string video_comment, double video_length, int video_number)
  : title(video_title), link(video_link), comment(video_comment), length(video_length), rating(video_number)
{
}

void Video::print(){

  cout << title << ", " << link << ", " << comment << ", " << length << ", " << rating << endl;

}


class Vlist {
 public:
  Vlist() {m_head = nullptr; }
  bool lookup(Video *other);
  void Insert(Video *video);
  void print();
 private:
 class Node {
        public:
                Node(Video *video, Node *next) {m_video = video; m_next = next; }
                Video *m_video;
                Node *m_next;
            };
            Node *m_head;
 };


void Vlist::Insert(Video* video)
{
    if (m_head == NULL || m_head->m_video -> GetTitle() > video->GetTitle())
    {
        m_head = new Node(video, m_head);

    }
    else
    {
        Node *node = m_head;
        while (node->m_next != NULL && node->m_next -> m_video->GetTitle() < video->GetTitle())
        {
            node = node->m_next;
        }
        node->m_next = new Node(video, node->m_next);
    }
 }

bool Vlist::lookup(Video *other)
{
  Node *node = m_head;
  return node->m_next -> m_video->GetTitle() == other-> GetTitle();
}

 void Vlist::print()
 {
     Video *video;
     Node *node = m_head;

     while(node != NULL)
     {
        node -> m_video-> Video::print();
        node = node->m_next;
     }
 }


int main()
{
  string sort_type, url, comment, title, user;
    int rating;
    double length;
    int initial = 0, last = 0, number;

    Vlist *vlistObj= new Vlist();
    Video *videoObj;

    while (getline(cin,user)) {

        if(user == "insert")
        {
        getline(cin,title);
        getline(cin, url);
        getline(cin, comment);
        cin >> length;
        cin >> rating;
        cin.ignore();

        videoObj = new Video(title,url, comment, length, rating);
        vlistObj->Insert(videoObj);
        }

        if(user == "lookup")
        {
            getline(cin, title);
            if(vlistObj -> lookup(videoObj))
            {
                vlistObj->print();
            }
        }
        if(user == "print")
        {
            vlistObj->print();
        }
    }

}
```

> Also I do want to note that I am receiving a segmentation fault. But I do know that it is because of my code in lookup. The program runs and output correctly if I do not type **lookup**

Comment: `if (user == "lookup") ...` why is the variable `user` and not something like `function` or `action` or whatever? That's my first mental roadblock with what you're trying to do. You can separate this into two problems: 1. You want the word "lookup" to trigger the lookup function, and 2. You want the lookup function to actually lookup the item. if one of those already works, remove it from your question. It just muddies the waters.

Comment: Don't give "the complete code". Give the [example]. Providing one of those does two things: it makes it easier for readers of your question to grok what's going on, and usually the practice of making a [example] causes YOU to better understand the problem. When people make [example]s, half of the time they solve their own problem.

Comment: Go into your debugger. Tell me what the value of `other` is when you enter the `lookup` function.

Comment: @JohnFilleau Oh okay, I didn't know if people would understand my problem without including everything. Noted

Comment: @JohnFilleau Im honestly very new to programming. How do I go into my debugger to check? My professor said we can use a random pointer variable to check if the Title would return true or not. That's all `other` does

Comment: What are you using to compile/develop? An IDE like visual studio, or a command line tool like gcc? Something else?

Comment: @JohnFilleau I am using vim on Ubuntu for windows

Comment: what are you compiling with? gcc? You're compiling this somehow. vim doesn't compile. It's just a text editor.

Comment: @JohnFilleau g++, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is in the `Vlist::lookup` function, where the current node pointer points to `m_next` which then points to `m_video`: `m_next` is not required, `m_head` should point directly to `m_video`.

Here below the complete working code, I also changed something here and there to eliminate all warnings from my compiler

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class Video {

  public:
    Video(string video_title, string video_link, string video_comment, double video_length, int video_number);
    void print();
    const string& GetTitle() const { return title; }

  private:

    string title;
    string link;
    string comment;
    double length;
    int rating;

};


Video::Video(string video_title, string video_link, string video_comment, double video_length, int video_number)
  : title(video_title), link(video_link), comment(video_comment), length(video_length), rating(video_number)
{
}

void Video::print(){

  cout << title << ", " << link << ", " << comment << ", " << length << ", " << rating << endl;

}


class Vlist {
 public:
  Vlist():m_head(nullptr) {}     // init_list
  bool lookup(const string& title);  // gets user input directly
  void Insert(Video *video);
  void print();
  Video* get(const string& title);   // new:returns pointer in list with given title
 private:
 class Node {
        public:
                Node(Video *video, Node *next):m_video(video), m_next(next) {}   // init_list
                Video *m_video;
                Node *m_next;
            } *m_head;    // declared directly together with class definition
 };


void Vlist::Insert(Video* video)
{
    if (m_head == NULL || m_head->m_video -> GetTitle() > video->GetTitle())
    {
        m_head = new Node(video, m_head);
    }
    else
    {
        Node *node = m_head;
        while (node->m_next != NULL && node->m_next -> m_video->GetTitle() < video->GetTitle())
        {
            node = node->m_next;
        }
        node->m_next = new Node(video, node->m_next);
    }
 }

bool Vlist::lookup(const string& title)
{
  Node *node = m_head;
  while (node->m_next != NULL && node-> m_video->GetTitle() != title)
  {
    node = node->m_next;
  }

  return node-> m_video->GetTitle() == title; // there was one pointer too many here
}

 void Vlist::print()
 {
     Node *node = m_head;

     while(node != NULL)
     {
        node -> m_video-> Video::print();
        node = node->m_next;
     }
 }

Video* Vlist::get(const string& title) // returns required item from list
{
    Node *node = m_head;
    while (node != NULL) {
        if (node->m_video->GetTitle() == title)
            return node->m_video;
        node = node->m_next;
    }

return nullptr;
}


int main()
{
  string sort_type, url, comment, title, user;
    int rating;
    double length;

    Vlist *vlistObj= new Vlist;
    Video *videoObj;

    while (getline(cin,user)) {

        if(user == "insert")
        {
        getline(cin,title);
        getline(cin, url);
        getline(cin, comment);
        cin >> length;
        cin >> rating;
        cin.ignore();

        videoObj = new Video(title, url, comment, length, rating);
        vlistObj->Insert(videoObj);
        }

        if(user == "lookup")   // more than a few changes here
        {
            getline(cin, title);

            if (vlistObj -> lookup(title))
            {
                videoObj = vlistObj->get(title);
                videoObj->print();
            } else {
                cout << "not found!\n";
            }
        }
        if(user == "print")
        {
            vlistObj->print();
        }
    }

}
```

---

#### BIG EDIT

Previous version did not traverse the `Vlist` correctly.

Now `Vlist` is properly searched by the `lookup` command, that thus finally prints the correct `Video`.

Comment: You're still passing an uninitialized pointer into the `lookup` function that is then attempted-dereferenced. It's undefined behavior.

Comment: Hi @JohnFilleau the `videoObj` pointer gets assigned when the user inserts a film with `Vlist::insert`. Next-to-last line inside the first `if` in the `while` loop in `main`.

Comment: @Lingo Thank you this definitely worked. However, it is still printing everything. Any ideas to only print what I want to look up?

Comment: @SeanPixel : I hastened the publication of the previous version, that in fact was bugged because the list was not traversed properly. Now everything works as expected, `lookup` prints its own item.

Comment: you could get rid of the `Vlist::lookup` function completely, only use the newly introduced `Vlist::get`, to be honest

Comment: @Lingo Awesome, that worked! Thank you so much! One last question, do you know why it produces a zero at the end?

Comment: @SeanPixel : I don't see any zeros at the end of the run when I execute on g++, IDE Codeblocks. Perhaps this is the effect of `nullptr`. What did you type in order to get zero for an answer on the prompt?

Comment: @Lingo I honestly don't know. I was using was executing with g++ on codeblocks, but it gave me an additional `0` with an `endline`, but then I switched to ubuntu for windows and it didn't create any additional numbers or endline. Strange, but as long as it works, I doesn't matter for me haha

Answer (score 2):

**Overview**

Before looking at the specific issues, your code shows you are struggling with putting all the pieces together and are, in a sense, guessing and not paying particular attention to every line in your code. You can't code by just *"trying things and see if it works"*, that will just make you old, gray and frustrated. Take the time to know just exactly what your next lines of code needs to do, craft the line, and then craft a test to ensure it succeeds (or make friends with `gdb` and check there -- you indicated you are using g++)

Examples:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
// #include <stdlib.h>
// #include <cstring>
```

What were `stdlib.h` and `cstring` included for? And:

```
void Vlist::print()
{
    // Video *video;        /* unused */
```

and

```
    // int initial = 0, last = 0, number = 0;   /* unused */
```

How is `other` initialized? If you are passing a pointer to a `Video` object, that object must at minimum have the `title` initialized, so `GetTitle()` returns a meaningful value...

```
bool Vlist::lookup(Video *other)
{
  Node *node = m_head;
  return node->m_next -> m_video->GetTitle() == other-> GetTitle();
}
```

That doesn't really make much sense?

Take your time and slow-down, understand what you need to do, and then pick up the keyboard (not the other way around)

Be consistent with your use of syntax. You include `std::string` in places and then simply `string` in others relying on `using namespace std;`. See [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/364696)

Further, under no conditions in C++ is there ever a **space** surrounding `->`. That is an operator that joins an object and its member, with nothing in between.

**Specific Issues**

It is clear that what you have will not output the `Video` object that matches a lookup when you are attempting to print a `Vlist`. (doesn't make much sense to print the entire list in response to finding one title of interest). Your `lookup()` function cannot return `bool`, instead it must return a pointer to the node containing the title (if found) or `nullptr` if not found. That means you must save and validate the return in order to know which `Node` contains the record you want to print. Within `main()` that looks like:

```
        else if (user == "lookup") {
            if (getline(std::cin, title)) {
                videoObj = new Video (title);   /* you must construct a new videoObj */
                Video *video = nullptr;         /* you want a Video* pointer returned */
                if ((video = vlistObj->lookup(videoObj))) { /* lookup & assign return */
                    video->print();             /* output the video, not list */
                }
                else {
                    std::cout << "title not found: '" << title << "'.\n";
                }
            }
        }
```

Now that `videoObj` points to a `Video` object that has `title` initialized, the `lookup()` function can do it's job -- returning a pointer to the node within the list that contains that title (and all the rest of the information) or returning `nullptr` if the title isn't found. (note the `else` indicating to the user that condition)

A rewrite of `lookup()` that does just that would be:

```
Video *Vlist::lookup (Video *other)
{
    Node *node = m_head;
    
    while (node) {  /* iterate over nodes in list looking for title */
        if (node->m_video->GetTitle() == other->GetTitle())
            return node->m_video;           /* return pointer to node if found */
        node = node->m_next;
    }
    return nullptr;                         /* nullptr if not */
}
```

(**Note:** simply passing `other` as `std::string` makes more sense, but in case you need a `Video` object -- this is a minimal way to do it)

There were a litany of other cleanups needed, tweaks to initializations, syntax fixes -- removing spaces around `->`, etc... that are too numerous to mention. Not to mention to need to ensure you are not leaking memory -- that is left to you (and your properly written destructors) Use `valgrind` to verify you are freeing all memory before your program exits.

Putting the syntax clean ups and initializations together, you could do something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

class Video {

  public:
    Video ( std::string video_title, std::string video_link, std::string video_comment, 
            double video_length, int video_number );
    void print();
    const std::string& GetTitle() const { return title; }

  private:
    std::string title {}, link {}, comment {};
    double length;
    int rating;
};


Video::Video ( std::string video_title = "", 
                std::string video_link = "", 
                std::string video_comment = "", 
                double video_length = 0, int video_number = 0)
                : title(video_title), link(video_link), comment(video_comment), 
                length(video_length), rating(video_number)
{
}

void Video::print()
{
    std::cout << title << ", " << link << ", " << comment << ", " << 
                length << ", " << rating << '\n';
}


class Vlist {
    
  public:
    Vlist() { m_head = nullptr; }
    Video *lookup (Video *other);
    void Insert (Video *video);
    void print();
  
  private:
    class Node {
      public:
        Node (Video *video = nullptr, Node *next = nullptr) {
            m_video = video; m_next = next;
        }
        Video *m_video;
        Node *m_next;
    };
    Node *m_head;
};

void Vlist::Insert (Video* video)
{
    if (m_head == nullptr || m_head->m_video->GetTitle() > video->GetTitle()) {
        m_head = new Node (video, m_head);
    }
    else {
        Node *node = m_head;
        while (node->m_next != nullptr &&
                node->m_next->m_video->GetTitle() < video->GetTitle()) {
            node = node->m_next;
        }
        node->m_next = new Node(video, node->m_next);
    }
 }

Video *Vlist::lookup (Video *other)
{
    Node *node = m_head;
    
    while (node) {  /* iterate over nodes in list looking for title */
        if (node->m_video->GetTitle() == other->GetTitle())
            return node->m_video;           /* return pointer to node if found */
        node = node->m_next;
    }
    return nullptr;                         /* nullptr if not */
}

void Vlist::print()
{
    Node *node = m_head;

    while (node != nullptr) {
        node->m_video->Video::print();
        node = node->m_next;
    }
}


int main (void) {
    
    std::string sort_type {}, url {}, comment {}, title {}, user {};
    int rating = 0;
    double length = 0;

    Vlist *vlistObj = new Vlist();
    Video *videoObj = nullptr;

    while (getline(std::cin, user)) {
        if (user == "insert") {
            if (getline (std::cin, title) &&
                getline (std::cin, url) &&
                getline (std::cin, comment) &&
                std::cin >> length &&
                std::cin >> rating) {
                    std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                    videoObj = new Video (title, url, comment, length, rating);
                    vlistObj->Insert(videoObj);
            }
        }
        else if (user == "lookup") {
            if (getline(std::cin, title)) {
                videoObj = new Video (title);   /* you must construct a new videoObj */
                Video *video = nullptr;         /* you want a Video* pointer returned */
                if ((video = vlistObj->lookup(videoObj))) { /* lookup & assign return */
                    video->print();             /* output the video, not list */
                }
                else {
                    std::cout << "title not found: '" << title << "'.\n";
                }
            }
        }
        else if (user == "print") {
            std::cout << "\nlist content:\n";
            vlistObj->print();
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Input File**

To minimally exercise your code you need more than one node in your linked list. What about attempting to lookup a node that does not exist -- validate that code-path?

```
$ cat dat/ll_video2.txt
insert
Arthur Benjamin: Lightning calculation and other "Mathemagic"
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4vqr3_ROIk
Hard to believe.
15.25
4
insert
Arthur Benjamin: Some Other "Mathemagic"
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SomeOther
Hard to swallow.
25.25
7
lookup
Arthur Benjamin: Lightning calculation and other "Mathemagic"
lookup
Arthur Benjamin: Some Other "Mathemagic"
lookup
Mickey & Minnie do Disney
print
```

**Example Use/Output**

The results of the three lookups are handled correctly and the list contents print as they should in result to the `print` command input as the last line of input above:

```
$ ./bin/ll_video <dat/ll_video2.txt
Arthur Benjamin: Lightning calculation and other "Mathemagic", http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4vqr3_ROIk, Hard to believe., 15.25, 4
Arthur Benjamin: Some Other "Mathemagic", http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SomeOther, Hard to swallow., 25.25, 7
title not found: 'Mickey & Minnie do Disney'.

list content:
Arthur Benjamin: Lightning calculation and other "Mathemagic", http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4vqr3_ROIk, Hard to believe., 15.25, 4
Arthur Benjamin: Some Other "Mathemagic", http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SomeOther, Hard to swallow., 25.25, 7
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Oh, wow. Didn't realize I had so many errors. And yes, you're definitely right. I do need to look at what I want to accomplish before I start typing anything. Really appreciate you spending your time to help me correct my errors. Very informative. Thank you

Comment: No worries, glad to help. We all started at the same place. Look at what you need for `other` -- if you can just pass `std::string` to `lookup()` that makes things a lot easier. Good lock with your coding.